# Can I define a single function that handle the "change keyup" event defined on 2 input tags? is it a good idea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In the HTML code I have these 2 input fields:

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <input id="variazioneUlterioreSaldoInput" class="rightAlligned form-control" type="number" value="" min="0" step="0.01" style="width: 60%">
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="anticipo">Anticipo:</label>
    <input id="anticipoModaleUlterioreSaldo" class="rightAlligned form-control" type="number" value="" min="0" step="0.01" style="width: 25%">
</div>
```

These fields are editable and I have to perform the sum of these 2 values when the user change one of these. I have a jQuery function like the below which is performed when the user changes the value inside the first input:

```
$("#variazioneUlterioreSaldoInput").bind('change keyup', function() {
    console.log("VALUE CHANGED !!!");
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

My doubt is to implement my previous requirement is better implement 2 different jQuery functions each defined on the `change keyup` event of a specific input or can I define an unique function for the `change keyup` event on both my input tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the same event handler to both the elements by separating their selectors with a comma:

```
$('#variazioneUlterioreSaldoInput, #anticipoModaleUlterioreSaldo').on('change keyup', function() {
    console.log("VALUE CHANGED !!!");
    // calculate the sum of values here...
});
```

Using this pattern is good practice to follow as it's in keeping with [DRY principles](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/3-key-software-principles-you-must-understand--net-25161).

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#variazioneUlterioreSaldoInput, #anticipoModaleUlterioreSaldo").bind('change keyup', function () {
            console.log("VALUE CHANGED !!!");
            // DO SOMETHING
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="col-md-7">
    <input id="variazioneUlterioreSaldoInput" class="rightAlligned form-control" type="number" value="" min="0" step="0.01" style="width: 60%">
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="anticipo">Anticipo:</label>
    <input id="anticipoModaleUlterioreSaldo" class="rightAlligned form-control" type="number" value="" min="0" step="0.01" style="width: 25%">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```